# Sharper than a sword, smoother than silk

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> Look towards me, I was there at the start,
> Open your mouth, I represent your heart.
>
> Go towards the voice, it is me who you'll find,
> Of covenants and deals, I can be used to bind.
>
> Sought for by those, who are seeking the truth.

What am I?

Hint:

> The first line is a religious reference.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

My guess:

> Word.
>
>  "I was there at the start" -- "In the beginning was the word" (St. John).
>  "Go towards the voice, it is me you'll find" -- Words are what the voice forms
>  "Of covenants and deals, I can used to bind" -- "My word is my bond."
>  Also, LOGOS (in addition to meaning "reason", as previous posters mentioned) can mean "word".

[edit] Hmmm, I just noticed the hint. I'll stand by my guess.

Comment: Good job, this is correct. On a side note, it's not Genesis, but St John where it mentions the verse... St. John 1:1

Comment: Hmmm, so it is. That's what I get for assuming I knew my Genesis, I guess.

Comment: The second line could also be a biblical reference, "... For out of the abundance of the heart his mouth speaks" Luke 6:45 (NKJV)

Comment: The hint matches your guess pretty well: [See in Google](https://www.google.com/search?&q=In+the+beginning+was+the+Word&oq=In+the+beginning+was+the+Word)

Comment: The title gives it away, Hebrews 4:12 reads "For the word... sharper than any double-edged sword... it judges the thoughts and attitudes of the heart"

Comment: @PatJ The confusion is understandable.  John is deliberately referencing Genesis in that bit of his gospel

Answer (score 5):

It is

> Word. As noted by others, the first letter of the lines spell LOGOS,which in ancient Greek means a lot of things, but primarily "word".

Look towards me, I was there at the start,

> The prologue of the Gospel of John says: "In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was God".

Open your mouth, I represent your heart.

> The words we say represent our heart.

Go towards the voice, it is me who you'll find,

> If you follow a voice you're probably following words.

Of covenants and deals, I can be used to bind.

> "To give one's word" means to bind a contract with ones honour.

Sought for by those, who are seeking the truth.

> The Word as in the Christian sense, I think.

Comment: Ah, I just saw that others posted the correct solution while I was writing... nevermind then :)

Comment: No problem. The last line I was actually thinking, "You have my word," for reassurance that someone isn't lying to them.

Comment: Λόγος is used in modern Greek as well, good answer!

Answer (score 3):

Is it

> Logic? The acrostic reads "Logos" which is logic in latin.

Comment: As I mentioned to Aelyn, it's not logic. Though I would follow the thread you are on a little more.

Answer (score 3):

It is:

> The Word

Because:

> At the beginning was the word.
>
>  The word cuts sharper than the sword, but can be smooth as silk
>
>  You give your word to seal a deal
>
>  The heart part is also a religious reference

Comment: This is correct but Pat J beat you to it by a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 2):

is it

> Tongue

Sharper than sword, smoother than silk

Comment: This is as close as the answer can get to without being the actual answer. Both Pat J and njzk2 got the answer correct.

Answer (score 1):

Is It?

> the past? (or maybe history?).
> the past seems like it could fit pretty well!

Comment: No, it's not either of those.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! I was about to ask you to explain why you believe your answer fits the riddle, but that's probably unnecessary now that it's been confirmed as wrong. Nonetheless, in future, please a) explain how your answers fit the puzzle, and b) hide them inside spoiler tags (`>!`) to avoid potentially spoiling the solution for anyone who wants to have a go at the puzzle themselves. Thanks!

Comment: ah! thx, sry for my newbieness :p waltzing in here and ignoring the rules and all!

Comment: It's okay, we were all newbies once! Make sure you take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure of my answer, but here is my guess...

> logic
>  1.The first word of each line spells LOGOS, which is the Greek word for logic, a method of persuasion.
> Line 1:I'm not really sure what supports my answer here, but perhaps people are born to persuade?
>  Line 2:You will probably use persuasion to gain something you desire?
>  Line 3: You can use your logic to persuade someone to do something.
>  Line 4:You can use logic to persuade someone of the benefit they will gain in making a deal.
>  Line 5:You can use logic to persuade someone that you are telling the truth, perhaps.

Comment: This isn't the answer, but I really like the guess.

Answer (score 1):

Is it?

> wisdom tooth? or wisdom?

Because

> according to Solomon's Proverbs, speaking about **wisdom** it says:The LORD possessed me **at the beginning** of His way,Before His works of old. I have been established from everlasting,**From the beginning**, before there was ever an earth. - Proverbs 8:22-23

And

> Wisdom tooth is obviously inside the mouth and looks like a heart.

And

> Those who made covenants and seeking for truth obviously needs wisdom.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE, Do take the [tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) to familiarize yourself with the site as well as earn a badge for yourself.